# Python pandas generate a table for multiple output variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have accident data and part of this data includes the year of the accident, degree of injury and age of the injured person. this is an example of the DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['2010', '2010','2010','2010','2010','2011','2011','2011','2011'], 
                        'Degree_injury': ['no_injury', 'death', 'first_aid', 'minor_injury','disability','disability', 'disability', 'death','first_aid'],
                        'Age': [50,31,40,20,45,29,60,18,48]})

print(df)
```

[image]

I want three output variables to be grouped in a table by year when the age is less than 40 and get counts for number of disabilities, number of deaths, and number of minor injuries.

**The output should be like this**:

[image]

I generated the three variables (num_disability, num_death, num_minor_injury) when the age is < 40 as shown below.

```
disability_filt = (df['Degree_injury'] =='disability') &\
                   (df['Age'] <40)
num_disability = df[disability_filt].groupby('Year')['Degree_injury'].count()
death_filt = (df['Degree_injury'] == 'death')& \
                    (df['Age'] <40)
num_death = df[death_filt].groupby('Year')['Degree_injury'].count()
minor_injury_filt = (df['Degree_injury'] == 'death') & \
                   (df['Age'] <40)
num_minor_injury = df[minor_injury_filt].groupby('Year')['Degree_injury'].count()
```

**How to combine these variables in one table to be as illustrated in the above table**?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pivot_table` after filter your rows according your condition:

```
out = df[df['Age'].lt(40)].pivot_table(index='Year', columns='Degree_injury', 
                                       values='Age', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
print(out)

# Output:
Degree_injury  death  disability  minor_injury
Year                                          
2010               1           0             1
2011               1           1             0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# prep data
df2 = df.loc[df.Age<40,].groupby("Year").Degree_injury.value_counts().to_frame().reset_index(level=0, inplace=False)
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Degree_injury': 'Count'})
df2['Degree_injury'] = df2.index
df2
#                   Year    Count   Degree_injury
# death             2010    1       death
# minor_injury      2010    1       minor_injury
# death             2011    1       death
# disability        2011    1       disability

# pivot result
df2.pivot(index='Year',columns='Degree_injury')
#       death   disability  minor_injury
# Year          
# 2010  1.0     NaN         1.0
# 2011  1.0     1.0         NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mnist for your feedback.